# I want to render static html in Express.js, but still have app.get() methods for logic

Tags: html, node.js, express, static

This seems like a ridiculous thing to be hung up on, but I would like to display html files from within `app.get()` methods. It seems like every answer I've come across uses the solution `app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));`, but then that does not allow for logic from the server.

What I would like to do, is have my .html files be rendered by express, so I can keep some basic logic:

```
app.get('/', function(res, req) {
  if (condition) {
    res.render('this.html');
  }
  else {
    res.render('that.html');
  }
}
```

It seems so silly to me that this is only meant for template files, and that I must not be seeing something simple to make this work.

Edit: Using sendFile does not seem to allow the HTML to include external files, javascript / css.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use res.sendfile() (res.sendFile() for new version) to render html files.

**Update for question in comment:**

You can include your css and javascript files in the html file (you might need to specify the paths for your resources correct to get them loaded):

```
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mystyle.css">
    <script src="myscripts.js"></script>
</head>
```

Comment: Ah wait! This seems to not be loading my sourced javascript and stylesheets, is there a way to fix that?

Comment: Ah yes, I needed to add back the line: app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public')); to my server